# CuPy running out of memory

Tags: python, chainer, cupy

I have been testing the CuPy library and done a simple matrix multiplication using einsum:

```
C = cp.einsum('pqrs,rs->pq', A, B)
```

Dimensions of A and B are, (41, 41, 41, 41) (41, 41), receptively. I also checked their sizes, which are 22606088 bytes, 13448 bytes.

```
While running the code, I am getting the following error message:
OutOfMemoryError: out of memory to allocate 38000834048 bytes (total 38023468032 bytes)
```

It indicates that I am running out of memory. Is there any option to sent data partially to the device and perform operations in terms of batches?

Comment: What CuPy version are you using? Could you add the output of `cupy.show_config()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no option to send data partially for one-array.

And I faced same issue before, this may be caused because the cupy einsum efficiency is not optimized yet.
https://github.com/cupy/cupy/issues/19#issuecomment-322972682

If you can try replacing your einsum function by using `transpose`, `reshape` and `matmul` etc, please try those.

I guess

```
C = cp.einsum('pqrs,rs->pq', A, B)
```

is equivalent to

```
p, q, r, s = A.shape
A = cp.reshape(A, (p, q, r*s))
B = cp.reshape(B, (1, 1, r*s))
C = cp.sum(A * B, axis=2)
```

Comment: You are right, this way works. It looks the CuPy einsum is not optimized. I also noticed that this library does not work if the available memory is excited, what is a huge drawback. Well, we know that GPU cards do not provide to much memory. Have you tried to go around it?

Comment: I think `einsum` implementation is updated, I don't know which cupy version you are using but latest version may work more efficiently.